# How to instantiate an Object inside a Base class in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a ModelBase class and I  am subclassing from it with a few classes (i.e Task, Milestone, etc). I want to create a static method named "all" that will fetch all the models (let's say an array)  but I want the array to be of of type [Task]  not [ModelBase]. Though I don't want to write that method for each subclass if possible.

```
class Task: ModelBase {
    override class var tableName : String {return "Task"}
```

}

Then I can do:

```
Task.all({ (tasks:[Task]) in  
   // do stuff with tasks
});
```

So far I have been using type(of: self) to access class level variables inside of non static / class methods.

However, I would like to have a static method that can fetch models from the API but I can't figure out how to reference the current class (i.e Task in this case)

Please let me know if what I am trying to do makes sense / is possible. Here is my sample code fetching from parse.

```
class ModelBase: NSObject {

// THIS WORKS FINE --->
class var tableName : String {return "ModelBase"}

init(_ _dictionary: [String: Any]) {

        self.dictionary = _dictionary
        _parseObject =  PFObject(className: type(of: self).tableName)
}

// THIS IS WHAT FAILS --------------> 
 class func all(_ success: @escaping ([ModelBase]) ->(), failure: @escaping (Error) -> ()){
    var models  = [ModelBase]()
    let questsQuery = PFQuery(className: ModelBase.tableName)

    questsQuery.findObjectsInBackground {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            failure(error)
        } else {
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    models.append(  ModelBase(parseObject: object as PFObject))
                }
                success(models)
            } else {
                success([])
            }
        }
    }
} 

}
```

Comment: I'm confused.... What are you asking?

Comment: You can simplify this code a bunch: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/99ca90c302e358ec3d2e3bf72e3c8f58

Comment: Can you make a minimal demonstration of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure thing @AlexanderMomchliov just updated. Let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: This would be much simpler if you made `all` just return `[SomeType]?`, which you can then handle. If you need it to be async, too the whole thing into dispatch

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I am not exactly sure what you mean but I will investigate the dispatch approach. Thanks

Comment: Right now you're using a `success` and `failure` completion handler for extracting data from this function. This certainly works, but as complexity of your project increases, this becomes increasingly more difficult to navigate. `findObjectsInBackground` is asynchronous, but I presume it has a synchronous alternative (`findObjects`, perhaps?) which will allow you to simply return your result from your `all` function. From there, people can use the return result as they wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want this code to by polymorphous over any subclass of ModelBase. For this I would suggest using generics.

```
class func all<T: ModelBase>(_ success: @escaping ([T]) ->(), failure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
    let questsQuery = PFQuery(className: T.tableName)

    questsQuery.findObjectsInBackground {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            failure(error)
            return
        } 

        guard let objects = objects else {
            success([])
            return
        }

        let models = objects.map(T.init(parseObject:))
        success(models)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is almost it,  would I want to do T(parse:object: $0 as PFObject) instead though? I will try this.

Comment: Yes, I missed that

Comment: Is that cast to PFObject necessary? You can probably do: ` let models = objects.map(T.init(parseObject:))`

Comment: It is not :) Your solution seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing but assuming you want to replace `ModelBase.tableName` to something like `self.tableName` that gives your the current class table name instead of base class table name, you need to use `class func` so that it is overridable by subclass

```
class ModelBase {
    class func tableName() -> String {
        return "base"
    }

    class func all() {
        print(self.tableName())
    }
}

class UserModel: ModelBase {
    override class func tableName() -> String {
        return "user"
    }
}

ModelBase.all() // base
UserModel.all() // user
```

Comment: Thanks but I am actually not trying to override tableName necessarily. I will post above some clarifying points.